# How to add custom internal link to footer in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am trying to add internal link to the footer of our wiki on MediaWiki, using the guidelines in their [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer#See_also).

The goal is to add the code to the LocalSettings.php.
I am adding the code below to my LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgHooks['SkinAddFooterLinks'][] = function ( Skin $skin, string $key, array &$footerlinks ) {
    if ( $key === 'places' ) {
        $footerlinks['Page name to display'] = $skin->footerLink( 'Some desctription', 'Page' );
    };
};
```

I have changed different skins, but this does not work. I see only default pages (which I can hide by changing their contents to "-").
Also, I have tried to `echo var_dump($skin)` and this gives a white page (error, obviously). Also, I was trying `echo wfVarDump($skin)`, but the same result - white page.
It looks like somewhere the skin is not set properly. I mean, not by me, since I have added all the skins as described in their manuals and also the skins work completely properly, other than footer links.

The other thing is that all my Wiki is in Cyrillic and all the pages are named in Cyrillic. Can this be a problem?

However, I have tried (to test) a code as bellow too:

```
$wgHooks['SkinAddFooterLinks'][] = function ( Skin $skin, string $key, array &$footerlinks ) {
        if ( $key === 'places' ) {
            $footerlinks['Page name to display'] = $skin->footerLink( 'Some desctription', 'MediaWiki:Aboutsite' );
        };
    };
```

As you can see - there is a page, that is permanently present in the system (however, its content is a dash "-" now). But no luck to have this displaying via SkinAddFooterLinks.
I am using MediaWiki 1.39.3.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skin::footerLink needs two message keys. If this is set to nonexisting message key or the message is disabled, the link will not be generated, empty string will be returned instead

```
Skin::footerLink

Given a pair of message keys for link and text label, return an HTML link for use in the footer.

<?php
public function footerLink($desc, $page) { }
@param string $desc
The i18n message key for the link text. The content of this message will be the visible text label. If this is set to nonexisting message key or the message is disabled, the link will not be generated, empty string will be returned in the stead.

@param string $page
The i18n message key for the page to link to. The content of this message will be the destination page for the footer link. Given a message key 'Privacypage' with content 'Project:Privacy policy', the link will lead to the wiki page with the title of the content.

@return string — HTML anchor
```

You can create the message keys by creating pages in the MediaWiki namespace.

Example:

MediaWiki:Page-link-text

```
My link
```

MediaWiki:Page-link

```
Main_Page
```

The content of the first message page is just a word, the content of the second message page is the page you want to link to.

Example:

```
$footerlinks['my-link'] = $skin->footerLink( 'Page-link-text', 'Page-link' );
```

Comment: Dear Robis, this indeed works this way, but what I tend to do is to get internal link created by the MediaWiki framework on the fly with the footerLink() or similar method. This will help to just add an internal name of the page and the MediaWiki will create the fully qualified URL for it on the render. So far, I use this workaround: $footerlinks['page-id'] = '<a href="/index.php?title=Page name" title="Some description">Page name</a>'; The 'page-id' - is any name to distinct links in the footer for the renderer (it is not displayed).

Comment: My code editor tells me this, I'll test it with a proper message key

```
public function footerLink($desc, $page) { }

@param string $desc
```
The i18n message key for the link text. The content of this message will be the visible text label. If this is set to nonexisting message key or the message is disabled, the link will not be generated, empty string will be returned in the stead.

Comment: I tested it and it works, bot of the parameters need to be system messages, you can create them by creating pages in the MediaWiki namespace, example: MediaWiki:Page-link

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you! Now, I got it! Should be shown in the documentation of MadiaWiki footer help page, I believe. Thanks!

Comment: I added it to the documentation: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Manual%3AFooter&diff=5985757&oldid=5868531 

My VSCode editor showed a tooltip/hint when hovering the function (powered by PHP Intelephense extension I assume), showing the Class level documentation, https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classSkin.html#aeb87f07c26988ceefae15bccb173c9c3 for this function. Maybe a good recommendation for future MediaWiki development. Happy that I could helped you!